# Override a Plugin Function

Tags: plugins, php, filters, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using a WooCommerce plugin and it has a filter for emails I wish to override. The filter is declared as such:

```
public function __construct() {

        add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', array( $this, 'attach_ics_file' ), 10, 3 );

    }
```

As part of a Class:

```
class WC_Booking_Email_Manager
```

The function is:

```
public function attach_ics_file( $attachments, $email_id, $booking ) {
        $available = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_bookings_emails_ics', array( 'booking_confirmed', 'booking_reminder' ) );

        if ( in_array( $email_id, $available ) ) {
            $generate = new WC_Bookings_ICS_Exporter;
            $attachments[] = $generate->get_booking_ics( $booking );
        }

        return $attachments;
    }
```

This simply attaches an .ics calendar file to emails. I don't want this to occur.

In my functions.php, I tried:

```
remove_filter( 'woocommerce_email_attachments', array( $GLOBALS['WC_Booking_Email_Manager'], 'attach_ics_file' ), 10,3);
```

But this does not work.

My question is how do I stop attachements from occuring by overriding the function, but only in the context of this plugin? i.e. There are other plugins that make attachments and I do not want to stop them from doing so.

**Edit**

The following code is work around by using the filter in the code above and by returning an empty array. It is placed in functions.php of your theme.

```
function woocommerce_bookings_emails_ics_edits( $array ) {

    return array();
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bookings_emails_ics', 'woocommerce_bookings_emails_ics_edits', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: it's added in the construct, therefore it will be added only on instantiation, what is the object variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The following code is work around by using the filter in the code above and by returning an empty array. It is placed in functions.php of your theme.

It's not a 'work around'. That's the correct way to do it. But there is a shorter way to do the same thing.

WordPress has a function called `__return_empty_array()` that just returns `array()`. So if you want to empty an array with a filter, you can just use that:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_bookings_emails_ics', '__return_empty_array' );
```